# Understand how ethtool disable auto-negotation in Micrel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ethernet

I'm working on a custom Linux embedded board. It hosts a KSZ9031 as Ethernet controller.
From command line I'm able to set its parameters, like link speed and auto-negotiations using `ethtool`, example:

```
ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

I'm interested to understand how the driver sets the internal registers of the KSZ9031 after issuing this command.

I found [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/phy/micrel.c) repository, that should be the official Micrel header, with support for my specific chip. But I'm not able to find where the driver sets the internal registers.
[Here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/9331b6740f86163908de69f4008e434fe0c27691/drivers/net/ethernet/micrel) I cannot find the source file for my specific device.

Where should I look?

## UPDATE

Here the output of the `strace` command as suggested by Marco Bonelli:

```
# strace -f ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex full autoneg
 off
execve("/usr/sbin/ethtool", ["ethtool", "-s", "eth0", "speed", "10", "duplex", "full", "autoneg", "off"], 0xbec3bd04 /* 17 vars */) = 0
...
...
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
ioctl(3, SIOCETHTOOL, 0xbe9d4b48)       = 0
ioctl(3, SIOCETHTOOL, 0xbe9d4b48)       = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5b000
brk(0x7c000)                            = 0x7c000
ioctl(3, SIOCETHTOOL, 0xbe9d4b48)       = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Take a look at the output of `strace -f ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off` (you might need `sudo`), it will list all syscalls that `ethtool` uses to interact with the kernel (and therefore the driver) to set the specified options. That's a good starting point. Maybe add the relevant output to the question.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, thanks - question updated. It's the first time I'm using this command. I'm reading its manual page. In the meanwhile, any hint are very appreciated!

Comment: Ah, I also forgot to ask: kernel version and architecture (`uname -a`)? I suppose ARM 32bit from the `strace` output.

Comment: (I've shortened your `strace` output removing the initialization stuff and keeping only the relevant syscalls)

Comment: What you found in sources is a PHY driver, the above function pretty much takes everything from Ethernet controller (MAC). You need to look into another driver.

Comment: @0andriy, the question is actually how to find out where to look into...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: `Linux mark4421a 4.19.49 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 9 07:17:25 UTC 2019 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: DTS, board datasheet or schematics, etc. Find what MAC is in use, PHY can be different.